# A proof problem in nonlinear optimization

Tags: optimization

[image]

To see the problem, the system has uploaded it on the top link.

This is a problem in textbook Nonlinear Programming theory and algorithms, cuold anyone help me with the problem especially in the c. and d. part? Thank you in advance for your consideration.

Comment: What ordering is being used on $\Bbb R^m$ to define $G_0$ and $G'$?  I assume it must be lexicographical but that probably should be explicitly stated somewhere.

Comment: Assuming that the order means elementwise, then c. is not true. Take $A= \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$, then $G' = (-\infty,0]$ and $(G')^\circ = (-\infty,0)$, but $G_0 = \emptyset$.

Comment: What textbook is this from?

Comment: Nonlinear Programming theory and algorithms